# How to interact with a javascript element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using ace editor (via jquery-ace-rails gem) to turn a textarea into a code editor.

```
<textarea class="my-code-area" rows="4" style="width: 100%">puts 'foo'</textarea>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-code-area').ace({ theme: 'twilight', lang: 'ruby' });
  });
</script>
```

I would like to create a link on the page to insert text into the editor:

```
<%= link_to 'Insert', '#', :onclick => 'ace.insert("Something cool");' %>
```

Any help appreciated - I have not worked with javascript before. Once I get it working I will do it in a less obtrusive way.

This might be relevant:
http://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/ particularly the "Access to ACE Code Editor instance" section.

Comment: look at the section `Access to ACE Code Editor instance` in http://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/

Comment: so try `$('.my-code-area').data('ace').ace.insert("Something cool");` instead of `ace.insert("Something cool");`

Comment: Thanks Arun. I linked that in my question. I know the information is there I have just never worked with Javascript before and can't for the life of me fit it together.

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object .my-code-area has no method 'data'

Comment: try `jQuery('.my-code-area')` instead of `$('.my-code-area')`

Comment: also try to use jQuery event handlers instead of using inlined event handlers

Comment: I tried with jQuery and nothing happens at all. I don't know what jquery event handlers are unfortunately. I might have to read up on the to get this working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the `ace` instance using the data property `ace` as given in the [documentation - Access to ACE Code Editor instance](http://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/)

So try jQuery('.my-code-area').data('ace').ace.insert("Something cool"); instead of ace.insert("Something cool");

Also try to use jQuery event handlers instead of using inlined event handlers so add either a class or an id to the link then remove the inline event handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.my-code-area').ace({
        theme: 'twilight',
        lang: 'ruby'
    });
    var decorator = $('.my-code-area').data('ace').editor;
    // ACE Code Editor instance
    var ace = decorator.ace;

    //if the link has the id insert-linl 
    $('#insert-link').click(function(){
        ace.insert("Something cool");
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Us42j/)

Comment: <%= link_to 'Insert', "#", id: 'insert-link' %>

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $('.my-code-area').ace({ 
        theme: 'twilight', 
        lang: 'ruby' 
      });
      
      var decorator = $('.my-code-area').data('ace');
      var ace = decorator.ace;
      
      //if the link has the id insert-linl 
       $('#insert-link').click(function(){
           ace.insert("Something cool");
       })
      
    });
  </script>

Comment: Still Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It's so simple it's frustrating.